# Am I eligible for tax refund if I shop before my residence permit starts?

Tags: turkey, turkish-citizens, uk-residents, tax-refunds

I'm a Turkish citizen and will get UK residence permit (Tier 2 visa) soon.

Turkish citizens living abroad are eligible for tax refund in Turkey according to [this](https://www.ytb.gov.tr/soru-cevap/gumruk) official website. It says that the departure should be within 3 months after the invoice date. I have no problem with that, but there is no specification regarding the residence permit start date.

May I get tax refund if I do shopping before my residence permit starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visited a [Global Blue](http://www.globalblue.com/) office in Istanbul and the answer I got was *NO*. They said that I have to reside abroad at least 6 months to be eligible for tax refund in Turkey.